# Recursive method cause stackoverflow

Tags: c#

I have a simple methode like this:

```
public int method(int a) 
{    
    if(// something)
    {
        methode(a); 
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

When the depth of calling increases, Visual Studio throws a **stackoverflow exeption.**

How can i solve this problem?
Is there any way to save return address and local data manually and implement a customized stack??

**I should note that I don't want to change my method to non recursive type.**

Comment: Please choose one tag for your language not all or remove all and add `language-agnostic`.

Comment: You forgot to tag Python.

Comment: We need more code. The exception is thrown because it gets stuck into an endless loop. Something that should only be done using a while-loop. So your code and/or the idea you have of how the function should behave is flawed. Show us a bit more code and detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: Dont you think you should do something to stop your code

Comment: It's very likely that your `if` condition never evaluates to `false`. Could you tell us what the `if` condition is?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in C# (and probably in Java etc) there is a [Stack<​T> class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx). For your method you can simply create a Stack and store the argument there. Iterate over the Stack until it's empty.

While this introduces an iterative loop, your algorithm is still recursive. (That is, depth first instead of breadth first)

Of course you need to make sure that your algorithm terminates eventually. This is just a way to increase stack space above what the operating system gives you. Windows allocates a certain amount of stack space for each process that suffices for most applications. If you need more, you can implement your own stack-like data structure on the heap. The heap is generally limited by the available RAM and the "bitness" of your application.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i solve this problem? Is there any way to save return address
>   and local data manually and implement a customized stack??

Recursive method should have a **termination point**, where from result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrease the depth of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int method(int a ){
//do stuff
  var something = ... //you have to make sure something turns false at some point
  if(something){ 
    method(a);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Dunken says - "you have to make sure something turns false at some point".

```
#define MAX 1000

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int methode(int a ){

    if(a>0 && a<MAX) return methode(a);

    return 0 ;

}// end

int main(void){


  methode(1);


  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: But why c++ in c# question?